# OpenCV Background Substraction c++

Tags: c++, opencv, background-subtraction

I've create a background Subsctractor (MOG) and now, I want to change some parameters:

```
Ptr< BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG, pMOG2;
pMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
pMOG.set("varThreshold",5); //does't work
pMOG->operator()(inputImage, outputImage); //works, but the output is not enought "sensitive"
```

Has anyone an idea how I could deal with this? I want to change the threshold value, because it returns an mask, that does not always detect my moving objects (e.g. if their color is nearly the backgrounds color).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` doesn't have a parameter named `varThreshold`. You probably wanted to set this parameter on `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`.

The parameters for `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` are:

```
"history"
"nmixtures"
"backgroundRatio"
"noiseSigma"
```

while for `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` are:

```
"history"
"nmixtures"
"varThreshold"
"detectShadows"
"backgroundRatio"
"varThresholdGen"
"fVarInit"
"fVarMin"
"fVarMax"
"fCT"
"nShadowDetection"
"fTau"
```

You can find these info in [video_init.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_attic/blob/master/opencv/modules/video/src/video_init.cpp) (checked for OpenCV version 2.4.9).

---

You can also set some parameters directly into the constructor, which is probably the safest way.

Comment: Thanks! Could you write an example line how to change an value (e.g. noiseSigma) and which command to use? `pMog.set` does not work. Maybe it's because of the <Ptr> ?